# Namespace error with service reference

Tags: c#, service-reference, qlikview

I am attempting to use the Qlikview API within my application. I have added the service reference and have set it up according to their instructions but I am getting a warning message that I believe is preventing me from being able to use the reference.

The message says

```
ISerializable type with data contract name 'Exception' in namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System' cannot be imported. The data contract namespace cannot be customized for ISerializable types and the generated namespace 'Tool.QMSAPIService' does not match the required CLR namespace 'System'. Check if the required namespace has been mapped to a different data contract namespace and consider mapping it explicitly using the namespaces collection. 
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://ws.qliktech.com/QMS/11/']/wsdl:portType[@name='IQMS']
```

There are a couple of other warning messages but I think that this is probably the main one, and fixing this will fix the others.

Can anyone give me some ideas on what to look for that might be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some code is raising an Exception of type System.Exception.  Because of that, that object is not serializable, and can't be returned, is what the error is saying.  The issue could be either a:

- bug on their end
- an issue with the input you are providing them.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will try to get in contact with them to see if I can some verification on the issue